# Differential Equation question about 2nd order linear de, showing constants can be chosen in one way only

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Verify that $y=c_1x^{-1}+c_2x^5$ is a solution of
$$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-3x\frac{dy}{dx}-5y=0$$
on any interval $[a,b]$ that does not contain the origin. If $x_0 \neq 0 $, and if $y_0$ and $y_0'$ are arbitrary, show directly that $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be chosen in one and only one way so that $y(x_0) = y_0$ and $y_0'(x_0)=y_0'$

I have verified the solution of the differential equation. How to show that $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be chosen in one and only one way?

**My attempt:**
Well, the general solution is $y=c_1x^{-1}+c_2x^5$ so we can say: $y_1(x)=\frac{c_1}{x}$ and $y_2(x)=c_2x^5$ are solutions.

This requires: $y_1(x_0) = \frac{c_1}{x_0}$ and $y_1'(x_0)=-\frac{c_1}{x_0^2}$

Also $y_2(x_0)=c_2x^5$ and $y_2'(x_0)=5c_2x_0^4$

But, I am not sure how to continue from here (nor if this start is correct).

Thank you in advance.

(Note: this question was asked here: [verification of solution of differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466387/verification-of-solution-of-differential-equation), was about the verification part, not the proof part.)

Comment: Hint: $c_1$ and $c_2$ are solutions to the system of linear equations
$$
\begin{cases}
y(x_0)=c_1x_0^{-1}+c_2x_0^5=y_0 \\
y'(x_0)=-c_1x_0^{-2}+5c_2x_0^4=y_0'
\end{cases} 
$$
How many solutions are there?

Comment: Solving the system for $c_2$:

 $$c_2 = \frac{x_0y_0+y_0'}{6x_0^4}$$ and back substituting will give similar expression for $c_1$, so $c_1$ and $c_2$ have fixed values for each fixed value of $x_0$, $y_0$, and $y_0'$? Thus, it is the only way of choosing them.
Thanks @Gonçalo, you can post as "answer" rather than comment so I can tick it & upvote :)